# A question on transformation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

I am doing a transformation problem of getting the graph of $\sin (2x – \pi/6)$ by applying transformations to $F(x) = \sin x$

In the process, I let $f(x) = F(2x) = \sin 2x$.

Next, I then let $g(x) = f(x – \pi/12) = \sin 2[x – \pi/12] = \sin (2x – \pi/6)$. The graphs are plotted as shown.

[image]

From f(x) to g(x), the above equations clearly shows there is a phase-shift of $\pi/12$ and this agrees with the red and blue lines

However, if I just comparing the functions $\sin (2x)$ and $\sin (2x – \pi/6)$ directly, shouldn’t there be just a right shift of $\pi/6$?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here the graph is plotted as  functions of *x*, taking values of *x* in the horizontal axis. So there is a shift of $\pi/12$.

If we plot it as a function of *2x*, then we would have a shift of $$2.\frac{\pi}{12} = \frac{\pi}{6}$$

Comment: Right. I forgot I have to plot it as function of 2x.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your reasoning, I presume you want to use the fact that the transformation
$$f(x)\to f(x+a)$$
corresponds to a horizontal shift of the function by $|a|$ (where the direction depends on the sign of $a$)

Nonetheless, when the function is of the form 
$$\sin(2x)$$ in order to obtain the function
$$\sin(2x-\pi/6)$$
you need to find $a$ such that
$$\sin({\color{red}2}(x+a))=\sin(2x+\color{red}{2}a)=\sin(2x-\pi/6)$$
and thus the needed shift is $a=\frac{\pi/6}{2}=\frac{\pi}{12}$.

But this does not contradict the property of the transformation: if you want to shift the function $f(x)=\sin(2x)$ by $\pi/6$ to the right then you do apply the transfomration as usual
$$f(x-\pi/6)=\sin(\color{red}{2}(x-\pi/6))=\sin(2x-\pi/3)$$
but as you see the actual shift is hidden by the factor 2.

In general, when constructing an harmonic oscillation of the form $\sin(\omega x+\varphi)$ you need to translate/shift the function horizontally by $\varphi/\omega$